# Kernel versions 2.6.24 and 2.6.32 device_create

Tags: function, linux-kernel, device

I am using the function to create device **device_create()**
but its creating a Warning in Ubuntu 8.04 kernel version 2.6.24:

> Warning: too many arguments for format

Here is how i am using this function:

```
device_create(my_class, NULL, MKDEV(major, 0), NULL, "my_dev");
```

This same code is working fine with **Ubuntu 10.04 - *kernel version 2.6.32*** but creating a warning in **Ubuntu 8.04 - *kernel version 2.6.24***!

can anyone please make my correction to remove that warning?

Thank you in advance.
Sindhu

Answer (score 1):

The older API for this did not have the fourth argument for drvdata, which you supply as NULL.  So get rid of the NULL, and you should be fine.

That said, other API has changed as well, so expect other problems.  Consider defining some preprocessor macros that do the right thing across kernel versions.  For example:

```
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(2,6,26)
    #define my_device_create(a, b, c, d) device_create(a, b, c, NULL, d)
#else
    #define my_device_create(a, b, c, d) device_create(a, b, c, d)
#endif
```